# Is it possble to convert a number to decimal base ten using do while?

Tags: c++

I am using a Do While Loop to convert a number from specified base like binary to to decimal but I receive an error that states '==': operator has no effect; did you intend '='?. 
Also, the decimal is not generating a correct answer. I enter 2 for the first cin(base), 10! for the second cin(numberEnterInBase). After that the program keeps running while repeatedly displaying 0 on the console.

Comment: What programming language are you using in that do-while loop? Did you make it up yourself?

Comment: That's not how you assign to variables in C++. I recommend you start simple and master variable assignments before attempting more complicated stuff such as loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't analyzed what your code is doing but I can tell you the difference between `==` and `=`.

`==` is an equality comparison operator. It allows to check if the left hand side and the right hand side are equal, in which case it returns the `bool`ean value `true` otherwise `false`.

`=`, on the other hand, is an assignment operator. It allows you to give the value on the right-hand side to a variable on the left-hand side. So the compiler is right here in warning you that `'==': operator has no effect; did you intend '='?`

Therefore, inside your `do {...} while` loop you should be using `=` statements instead of `==`.